# The direct product of a soluble group with any group, results in a soluble group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I proved that the direct product of two solubles is soluble and I immediately had some questions in my head, is the product of a soluble with any group soluble? (If I were to kick, would I say no, some against example?)

Answer (score 4):

You're right, the answer is no.  Let $S$ be a soluble group, and let $G = S\times A_5$, where $A_5$ is the (simple) alternating group of degree $5$.  If $G$ were soluble, so would all of its subgroups be soluble.  But, it has an insoluble subgroup isomorphic to $A_5$.

Comment: Why not simply take $\{e\}\times G$ where $G$ is any non soluble group ?

Comment: @Max Sure, that would work too.  Anything of the form $S\times I$, with $S$ soluble and $I$ insoluble could form a counter-example.

Comment: It's just that it seemed simpler as $G\times\{e\} \simeq G$ :p but your answer is of course fine and provides a wider range of examples

Answer (score 1):

You proved that the direct product of two soluble groups is again soluble. But the *converse* holds too. This is because any quotient of a soluble group is again soluble. Hence if $G_1 \times G_2$ is soluble then $G_1 \cong (G_1 \times G_2) / (\{e\} \times G_2)$ is soluble. Same for $G_2$.